# using linq on active directories underlying object

Tags: c#, linq, active-directory, principalcontext

Currently my code is:

```
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, adDomain))
{
    using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(context)))
    {
        foreach (Principal result in searcher.FindAll())
        {
            DirectoryEntry entry = result.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
            if (entry.Properties["Company"].Value?.ToString() == "My Company")
            {
                // do some stuff
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I was just wondering if it would be possible to do a LINQ statement instead of the `if` statement to only get entries I am interested in.

Something like this:

```
foreach (var entry in searcher.FindAll()
    .Where(x => x.GetUnderlyingObject<DirectoryEntries>()
    .Properties["Company"].Value?.ToString() == "MY Company"))
{
    // do some stuff
}
```

Comment: It actually returns object. And Bryan you don't have generic `GetUnderlayingObject` method add `Cast<DirectoryEntry>()` after `Where`...

Comment: Please take a look again. I follow your link. Return type is object.

Comment: @Johnny My mistake. The wording in the description that I pasted is what made me think that. You are correct. I've deleted my comments to eliminate confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be possible.  You can use `Select()` first to cast the object to the `DirectoryEntry`'s.  Something like this should work:

```
var entry = searcher.FindAll()
    .Select(x => (DirectoryEntry)x.GetUnderlyingObject())
    .Where(x => x.Properties["Company"].Value?.ToString() == "My Company")
    .FirstOrDefault();  // or .ToList() depending on your requirements

if (entry != null)
{
    // do some stuff
}
```

Comment: Good call on the `Select` to do the casting and the `GetDirectoryEntry()` call. I fixed my answer after reading this. Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need the `foreach`. Try this:

```
var myCompany = searcher.FindAll()
    .Select(x => (DirectoryEntry)x.GetUnderlyingObject())
    .Where(x => x.Properties["Company"].Value?.ToString() == "MY Company")
    .ToList();

if (myCompany != null)
    // Do something with myCompany
```

Off-topic: You can stack `using` statements to eliminate some nesting:

```
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, adDomain))
using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(context)))
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah Bryan, that looks like a solution. I don´t have the types of everything to test it, but that with a ToList() at the end to allow the foreach to iterate should work.

I would put it above the foreach in a var to see the list it produces before iterating.

Comment: well at the moment it gives a compile error stating PrincipalGetInderLyingObject() cannot be used with type arguments. hold on I'll make a fiddle.